# Stress Testing Managed Host with VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, load-testing, stress-testing

Is it possible to stress test a managed host (not my own machine) using VS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2008 doesn't really have built-in tools to test at any volume, but there are free ones out there:

- [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) - Made by apache, but usable against any web server
- [Web Capacity Analysis Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282) - Microsoft

Comment: Actually I was interested in knowing whether it is possible to stress test a web app on a shared managed hosting, to which I do not have administrative access and cannot install apps. I think the apps you suggested won't help in this case. Probably it is not possible at all, or is it?

Comment: @niaher - These apps aren't installed on the server...they're installed on one or more machines that work together to hit the web server, as if they were actual clients.  They should do what you're after...and if you're willing to pay, there's a lot more options out there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not free:[Visual Studio 2008 Team System Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182561.aspx) is a good stress test tool.

Comment: Good point Kb - I've only seen a handful of these installs before, I kind of dismiss it as "no one has it" but I guess it has to be out there, +1

Answer (score 0):

As stress test tool I liked "[Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/features.html)" a lot and found it easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to stress test against the external machine, however you will not be able to see any perfmon stats from the target machines.

You will also probably cause serious consternation with your hosting provider as a good load test stresses the network pretty hard. You may want to talk to them before going ahead.

From an external source you will also likely include network effects in your test, so different times of day will result in different network loads and different results.

Ideally you would want to install a load test controller and agent on a server on the same switch as the target to get high loads on your application. This does require a hefty licence however.

Visual Studion 2010 has better licencing for the Load Test Agent, but may be more expensive than you want.